# How to debug broken IE 8 when FF is fine

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, debugging

I spent a long time adding *a lot* of Javascript to our front-end. I did this all the while using FF (11.0). I just committed all the changes (which work fine on my local sandbox) to our dev server, and a QA tester noticed that an entire div is missing when viewing the page in IE 8.

This div does all sorts of fancy stuff with jQuery, allowing users to expand/collapse accordion panels, and drag-drop images from expanded accordions, etc.

It is 10 PM and I can't go to bed until I fix this break. I have tried using the IE Dev Toolbar that ships with IE (and is accessed via the `F12` button), hoping it would catch some bad Javascript but nodda. Same for Firebug. The JS looks perfectly fine, it's just IE being stubborn.

What steps would SO take to start figuring out why IE won't display my jQuery-heavy div? It's really not as simple as backing out the changes one by one, because my code sprinkled and interwove functions and calls all over the JS page. Thanks in advance for any pointers or nudges in the right direction.

Comment: What's broken? Can you give us a link?

Comment: See, if I were making this then I would work in IE *first*, then double-check it works in the so-called "better" browsers.

Comment: Add break points and walk through the code.

Answer (score 2):

*F12 Developer Tools*

The F12 Developer Tools, when used properly, are generally speaking more than capable of finding odd problems throughout your code. You can audit your application to find long-running processes, add breakpoints and watch variables through the life-cycle of your page.

*IE Compat Inspector(s)*

Another great tool is the IE Compat Inspector, which will examine your code and look for any types of patterns or usage that might break your site in Internet Explorer. You can find this online at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/04/27/ie9-compat-inspector.aspx for Internet Explorer 9, and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/01/20/ie10-compat-inspector.aspx for Internet Explorer 10.

*ECMAScript Compat Charts & Polyfills*

Often times we mix up what features are supported by which browsers. It helps to keep a good [compat chart](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/) handy, so you know if `classList` is supported in IE or not. If and when you discover that something isn't implemented in Internet Explorer, it's time to find a polyfill. Fortunately, [there are many](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills).

*Web Debugging Proxies*

These are just a few tools that you can use to trouble-shoot your site in Internet Explorer. Lastly is [Fiddler 2](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) (a web-debugging proxy), which permits you to stand in between the client and server, tampering with data as it goes both ways. I typically use this to serve up custom files in the place of live server files when I'm debugging scripts. However, if you've got direct access to the server presently, this isn't all that necessary.